# Does getting a prestige class that gives your base class an extra level increase your Eidolon's evolution points?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon

Does getting a prestige class that gives your base class an extra level like mystic theurge  increase your Eidolon's evolution points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Most prestige classes do not advance a summoner's eidolon.

Consider the [Mystic Theurge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Spells per Day**
> When a new mystic theurge level is gained, the character gains new *spells per day* as if he had also gained a level in any one arcane spellcasting class he belonged to before he added the prestige class and any one divine spellcasting class he belonged to previously. He *does not*, however, gain *other benefits a character of that class would have gained*. This essentially means that he adds the level of mystic theurge to the level of whatever other arcane spellcasting class and divine spellcasting class the character has, then determines *spells per day, spells known, and caster level* accordingly.

Mystic Theurge stacks with another spellcasting class for determining spells per day, spells known, and caster level **only**. It does *not* grant or improve any other class features, such as a wizard's familiar, a sorcerer's bloodline powers, or a summoner's eidolon.

There are a **few** prestige classes that advance *all* class abilities of another class, however. Note the difference between the Mystic Theurge and the [Evangelist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/evangelist/) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Aligned Class**
> Evangelists come from many different backgrounds, and they show an unusual range of diversity. At 2nd level, the evangelist must choose a class she belonged to before adding the prestige class to be her aligned class. She gains *all the class features* for this class, essentially adding every evangelist level beyond 1st to her aligned class to determine what class features she gains. She still retains the Hit Dice, base attack bonus, saving throw bonuses, and skill ranks of the prestige class, but gains *all other class features* of her aligned class as well as those of the evangelist prestige class.

Prestige classes that grant spells per day will **not** improve a summoner's eidolon in any way: no additional HD, evolution points, feats, or anything else. Only prestige classes that advance **all** of a base class' class features will improve a summoner's eidolon.